# Does the graph api not have a logout function?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, graph, logout

Seems like I should be able to log people out of my app using the graph api. Is that not possible?

Use case: wife logs in with facebook. Does some stuff. I want to log her out and log in as me so I can so some of my own stuff.

I figured that since I was using the graph api to login, I'd be able to logout as well. What am I missing here? This one should be obvious, right? Wasted a bunch of time looking for the answer.....

Comment: Or is there a way to expire an access token?

Comment: You can uninstall your app from a user by making a DELETE request to /<user id>/permissions which will invalidate that user's access token for your app

Answer (score 0):

You can do logout thing also.just refer this www.developors.facebook.com and after login search for graph api samples.they have given some samples on graph.there you will get logout.